# Is it okay to report zero eigen values for some PC components if the first few components are greater than one?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, pca, learning

I have a dataset which collected household responses over 3 years. It is unbalanced since not all households participated during the three surveys. I run multilevel PCA in stata to account for within and between variations. For comparison purpose I also run Overall PCA for the whole dataset considering data were independent.

Between and within PCA gave five and four eigen values which were greater than 1, however there were many eigen values with exactly zero.

However, the overall PCA had 11 PCs with eigen values greater than 1 and the rest were decreasing slowly and the had 0.14 eigen value.

Is it okay to report such kind of results? How can I interpret my results?